# editable list in cocoa touch/UIKit

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am new to cocoa touch programming.

Is there a widget/control in cocoa touch which will let me display a list of strings:

Apple
Mango
Papaya
...

and lets the user:

- edit the strings in-place

  add strings in between the existing items in the list.

  delete existing strings

  move the strings up/down one row.

Is there a widget that lets me do some of items 1 to 4, if not all of them?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You've basically defined the functions of a UITableViewController. Make sure that you search Google/Apple Documentation before posting on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no control to do that.

But you could achieve your control by subclassing UITableViewController

You'll have access to a list. And with a few setting you'll be able to move, add, and delete items.

You should read the [Apple guide about using Table View](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) :-)